# Item is not getting visible in Flat list

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

When my flat list is rendered...i am getting same item(item at index 0) in my rendered Item function and no data is visible in my flat list. I am new to react native...any help would be appreciated.

## This is my Class which contains Flat List  and in Render item function i am passing the item to another component which i have named as ListviewItem.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {FlatList,Text} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './LibraryList';


class LibraryList extends Component{


  componentWillMount(){
     console.log(this.props);
   }

   renderItem({item, index}) {
     console.log('render item called');
     console.log(item);
      return (
         <ListItem item={item} />
      );
    }


  render(){
    return(
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.libraries}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  console.log(state.libraries);
  return {libraries:state.libraries};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

## ListviewItem Class

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {CardSection} from './common';

class ListviewItem extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
         <CardSection>
            <Text>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
         </CardSection>
      );
    }
}

export default ListviewItem;
```

Comment: Wrap your Flatlist with View and set style to that view. `<View style={{flex :1} } > your Flatlist </View>`

Comment: Tried...No Sucess :(

Comment: this.props.libraries is not empty?

Comment: no its not Empty..data is there...but in render function only item at index 0 is comming and flat list also not visible.

Comment: What's the item it's printing, how many times is it getting called? Make sure <ListItem> is correctly imported

Comment: You may add a snack expo [here](https://snack.expo.io/), it is hard to debug without the styles .

Comment: yes i have added...you can check now.

Comment: @Vivek_Neel yes there was import problem...i have corrected it...but still my flat list data is not visible.

Comment: You can put your code on snack. Will check

Comment: As I saw you export an `ListviewItem` and import `ListItem`, who is `ListItem` ?

Comment: @oma yes i have corrected that import statement...but then also data is not visible in my flat list. :)

Comment: @Vivek_Neel  https://snack.expo.io/@neeraj010133/teck_stack

Comment: @PritishVaidya  yes i have added...please check it 

snack.expo.io/@neeraj010133/teck_stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this please:

```
<View>
   <FlatList
       data={this.props.libraries}
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ListItem item={item} />
       )}
    />
</View>
```

And the item like this:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {CardSection} from './common';

class ListItem extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
         <View>
            <Text>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
         </View>
      );
    }
}

export default ListItem;
```

So first remove the CardSection from your list item, check if is working, and if this is working take a look at `CardSection` where you add a text which has some props form his parent.

Comment: yes i have check with your code...Its not working... :(

Comment: Hmmm, i am using this code and it's working for me. Can you provide some details about the `this.props.libraries` please?

Comment: i am getting only this warning ->

virtualizedlist missing keys for items make sure to specify a key property on each item

Comment: you can check my code in ->

snack.expo.io/@neeraj010133/teck_stack

Answer (score 0):

Try this for item:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {CardSection} from './common';

class ListviewItem extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
         <CardSection>
            <Text>{this.props.item.item.title}</Text>
         </CardSection>
      );
    }
}

export default ListviewItem;
```